# How to serve an audio file from java API to the front end?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, audio, audio-streaming

I'm trying to send a request to an API through (t = textToSpeechService.callAPI(tmp);) and it returns an audio file. I tried serving it to the front end through the OutputStream but how do I actually serve the actual file i.e. wav file, since I need it afterwards to play and pause in the front end?

```
public Clip callAPI(Source src){
URL url;
Clip result = null;

AudioInputStream sound = null;
{
    try {
        url = new URL(" http://api.voicerss.org/?key=" + keyAPI + "&hl=" + src.getLang() + "&src=" + src.getSrc());

        sound = AudioSystem .getAudioInputStream(url); //here i have the audio
        Object sound2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
        AudioFormat at = sound.getFormat();
        result = AudioSystem.getClip();
        result.open(sound);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

return result;
}

Clip t = null;
AudioInputStream ais = null;
private TextToSpeechService textToSpeechService;
 public Clip theFunction(@RequestParam String src, HttpServletRequest request){
//if(src == request.getSession().getAttribute("input")){
Source tmp = new Source();
tmp.setSrc(src);

t = textToSpeechService.callAPI(tmp);


t.start();

return t;

}



 public void getHere(@RequestParam String src, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Source tmp = new Source();
    tmp.setSrc(src);
    ais = textToSpeechService.callAPI2(tmp);

    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(ais);

    response.setContentType("audio/wav");
    int readBytes = 0;
    while((readBytes= bf.read())!= -1){
        os.write(readBytes);
    }


}
```